# Authenticate traffic from PHP to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, authentication

I am trying to figure out how to authenticate incoming requests from another site.

Site A is a PHP based ecommerce solution belonging to a company other than us.
Site B is our own ASP.Net based web forms ordering system.

What I want to do is be able to have site A hit a web address that will include some sort of authentication along with order info (such as order id or similar)

I can't figure out if the right direction would be to do a query string setup with some sort public/private key?

All the examples of site to site authentication I have found do not cover a situation such as this.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe single sign on OpenAuth is what you're looking for: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/09/12/integrate-openauthopenid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers/

Comment: I thought about that, but since it's not a user logging in it would not apply. It would be Site A forwarding the user to Site B with some sort of authentication to prove it came from Site A and not something rouge.